# Implement ComponentCallbacks to listen for onConfigurationChanged

Tags: android, android-activity

There is [ComponentCallbacks interface](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/content/ComponentCallbacks.java#ComponentCallbacks) in android using by activity, ActivityGroup, service etc. They implements it and **someone** notify them when activity configuration changed. So, I want to create my own class which implements ComponentCallbacks listens for onConfigurationChanged and doing some actions... So my class is implementing, but... I guess I need to register my class in **someone's** observer.

So, is it possible? Is there any ways to "register" my own class to be notified when configuration changed?

I guess this someone may be ActivityThread and it's method collectComponentCallbacksLocked. But I did't see here any ways to register my own class.

[ActivityThread](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r1.2/android/app/ActivityThread.java#ActivityThread.collectComponentCallbacksLocked%28boolean,android.content.res.Configuration%29) and 
[ComponentCallbacks  using](http://www.kandroid.org/android_docs/android/content/class-use/ComponentCallbacks.html)

p.s. Of course I can override activity's method onConfigurationChange change and then call the onConfigurationChanged method of my class, but I don't want. I want to know if there is any way in android to do it.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" will work and it should work. And I want android to notify my own class which implements ComponentCallbacks that configuration changed

Comment: In the "Google I/O 2012 - Doing More With Less: Being a Good Android Citizen " talk (which you can find on youtube), it says that you can do this by calling Context.registerComponentCallbacks, but I tried this for my own app also, and this requires an input parameter, like this: context.registerComponentCallbacks(ComponentCallbacks callbacks), so I don't know should I create some instance of ComponentCallbacks.. I thought that implementing the wanted interface is enough (like class MyClass implements ...).

Comment: Good notice, Sandra! Please put your comment as answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the "Google I/O 2012 - Doing More With Less: Being a Good Android Citizen " talk (which you can find on youtube), it's explained that you can do this by calling `Context.registerComponentCallbacks`.
So, you just make your class implement the `ComponentCallbacks` interface (or `ComponentCallbacks2` as you wish), the methods that you can override are added automatically, and from your Activity, Fragment.. just pass the instance from your class to register to it. Something like this:

```
 registerComponentCallbacks( mYourClass );
```

That should do the work :)

Answer (score 2):

According to @Sandra's answer we can use Context.registerComponentCallbacks to register our own component callbacks in the system and use it like this:

```
context.registerComponentCallbacks(new ComponentCallbacks() {

            @Override
            public void onLowMemory() {
                // make some operations when system memory is low
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
                // make some operations when configuration has been changed
            }
        });
```

All our registered callbacks will be called when system configuration changed / on low memory.

Method [registerComponentCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerComponentCallbacks%28android.content.ComponentCallbacks%29) available from API level 14. Checkout how it works [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/app/Application.java#Application.registerComponentCallbacks%28android.content.ComponentCallbacks%29)

Comment: If you want call onConfigurationChanged before API 14 you should override it in any needed classes. For example `Activity`, `Application` or any `View`. I do it in `LinearLayout` and placed in layout fixed class. Then if config changed and this layout on screen - method called. Do not forget call super implementation.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to register a BroadcastReceiver to receive this braodcast Intent:

`Intent.ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED`

That event is broadcast by the system any time the configuration changes.